# C# Search file for a string and get the string's line number

Tags: c#, io, lines

I've been at this all day and I'm struggling to do it, I've searched far and wide and though there are similar questions, there are no answers.

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm trying to search a file for multiple strings and receive the line numbers so that when users wish to change said strings inside my application, my application knows what lines to replace with their string.

**What I've tried so far:**
I've tried the below code, my attempt was to read the file then receive the line number, however it doesn't seem to be working at all.

```
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
            foreach (var match in lines // File.ReadLines(filePath)
                            .Select((text, index) => new { text, lineNumber = index + 1 })
                            .Where(x => x.text.Contains("motd=")))
            {
                lines[match.lineNumber] = "motd=" + textBox1.Text;
                File.WriteAllLines(filepath, lines);
            }
        }
```

What I expect the above code to do is find the string "motd=" in the file, get the line number and attempt to re-write it with what the user has inputted.

However, I receive this error: "`Index was outside the bounds of the array`".

Comment: Why are you writing to the file inside of the `foreach`?  You should only need to do that once after the `foreach`.  Also please define "doesn't seem to be working at all".  Are you getting exceptions?  Is the output not correct, and if so what are you getting vs. what you expect?

Comment: I figured for each match it found to replace with something else. This is because I intend to use multiple values in the future, however I'm just testing this. Also, I updated my original post with the error message and what I expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a `for` loop makes more sense here

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if(lines[i].Contains("motd="))
    {
        lines[i] = "motd=" + textBox1.Text;
    }
}

File.WriteAllLines(filepath, lines);
```

A couple of issues with your code was that you were writing out the file in side the loop and you incremented the index by 1 which would then point to the wrong line in the array and result in the exception you are getting if the last line contains the text you are searching for.

It should be noted that this could be a memory hog if you are working with a really large file. In that case I'd read the lines in one at a time and write them out to a temp file, then delete the original file and rename the temp at the end.

```
var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
using (var file = File.OpenWrite(tempFile))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filepath))
    {
        if (line.Contains("motd="))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("motd=" + textBox1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}

File.Delete(filepath);
File.Move(tempFile, filepath);
```

Comment: This appears to have done the trick! Thanks a bunch, especially for the rapid response! Would this be doable with say 10-20 extra values?

Comment: Was trying to come up with an answer before you did, but it seems yours is much better. Mine would have utilized StreamReader, and Peek(), but definitely will not be better than yours.

Comment: @TaylaWilson You could certainly add `else if` statements, or maybe a `switch` statement to handle more than one cases.

Comment: The file is around 40 lines long with around 20 chars on each line, would this be considered a large file?

Comment: @TaylaWilson No, that would be considered extra small.

Answer (score 3):

This will be much faster, and use less memory, and work with very large files, but you need to write to a new file:

```
File.WriteAllLines(filepath2,
  File
    .ReadLines(filepath)
    .Select(x=>x.Contains("motd=")?"motd="+TextBox1.Text:x));
```

It uses ReadLines which reads each line as it can instead of reading the entire file and breaking it into lines in one step.  So it processes it as quickly as your file system can read, processes the line, then writes the result.

A complete replacement would look like this:

```
var filepath2= Path.GetTempFileName();
File.WriteAllLines(filepath2,
  File
    .ReadLines(filepath)
    .Select(x=>x.Contains("motd=")?"motd="+TextBox1.Text:x));
File.Delete(filepath);
File.Move(filepath2, filepath);
```

To do multiple values:

```
var filepath2= Path.GetTempFileName();
File.WriteAllLines(filepath2,
  File
    .ReadLines(filepath)
    .Select(x=> {
      if (x.Contains("motd=")) return "motd="+TextBox1.Text;
      if (x.Contains("author=")) return "author="+TextBox2.Text;
      return x;
    }));
File.Delete(filepath);
File.Move(filepath2, filepath);
```

or move the replace logic to it's own function:

```
string ReplaceTokens(string src)
{
  if (src.Contains("motd=")) return "motd="+TextBox1.Text;
  if (src.Contains("author=")) return "author="+TextBox2.Text;
  return src;
}
var filepath2= Path.GetTempFileName();
File.WriteAllLines(filepath2,
  File
    .ReadLines(filepath)
    .Select(ReplaceTokens));
File.Delete(filepath);
File.Move(filepath2, filepath);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're writing the file on every single iteration which makes no sense, and doing a select/where/index thing is just weird.

Since you're doing a `Where` you have to iterate over every single line, so why not save the trouble and just iterate over everything explicitly?

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if(lines[i].Contains("motd="))
    {
        lines[i] = "motd=" + textBox1.Text;
    }
}

File.WriteAllLines(filepath, lines);
```

Comment: Thanks also for the help! Yours and juharr's are exactly the same haha! That quick!

Comment: @TaylaWilson you're welcome. Great minds think alike I guess!